# How to change DataGridViewComboBoxCell to DataGridViewTextBoxCell?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to change one cell inside a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn from 
DataGridViewComboBoxCell into a DataGridViewTextBoxCell

here is the line i am typing in order to change it:

```
dataGridView1[0,3] = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
```

after running this line the cell remains in its DataGridViewComboBoxCell type.

Thanks in advance,
Nadav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot distinguish any problems. The following form creates a `DataGridView` and provides a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` with three items `asdf` `qwer` and `yxcv` as possible combinations. During the `Load` event of the `Form` the grid is filled with four valid rows. Afterwards your line of code is performed, which performs as expected.

Am i missing something?

Here is the code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1() { InitializeComponent(); }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add("asdf");
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add("qwer");
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add("yxcv");
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add("asdf");

        dataGridView1[0, 3] = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
    }
}
```

Designer File's code:

```
partial class Form1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Erforderliche Designervariable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Verwendete Ressourcen bereinigen.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">True, wenn verwaltete Ressourcen gelöscht werden sollen; andernfalls False.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Vom Windows Form-Designer generierter Code

    /// <summary>
    /// Erforderliche Methode für die Designerunterstützung.
    /// Der Inhalt der Methode darf nicht mit dem Code-Editor geändert werden.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.dataGridView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
        this.Column1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).BeginInit();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // dataGridView1
        // 
        this.dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
        this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
        this.dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
        this.Column1});
        this.dataGridView1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
        this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(470, 262);
        this.dataGridView1.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // Column1
        // 
        this.Column1.HeaderText = "Column1";
        this.Column1.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
        "asdf",
        "qwer",
        "yxcv"});
        this.Column1.Name = "Column1";
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(470, 262);
        this.Controls.Add(this.dataGridView1);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).EndInit();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dataGridView1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxColumn Column1;
}
```